# Constructing integral curve passing through three points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $p_0 =(0,0), p_1=(1,0)$ and $p_2=(1,1)$. I want to construct a smooth vector field $V$ on $\Bbb R^2$ such that the the maximal integral curve $\gamma : I\to \Bbb R^2$ of $V$ starts at $p_0$ and goes through all the points $p_0,p_1,p_2$. How can I do this?

I thought about the circle $(x-1/2)^2   +(y-1/2)^2 = 1/2$ which contains all of the given points and so I would like to consider $V$ such that the integral curve traces out this circular region.

Would $V = -(y-1/2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + (x-1/2)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ work here? I'm sort of stuck on solving the system
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -(y-1/2) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= (x-1/2)
\end{align*}
to see and verify whether the resulting integral curve will pass through the points.

Comment: Make an obvious change of variables.

Comment: Polar coordinates? @TedShifrin

Comment: You certainly could do that, but I was thinking of getting rid of the $1/2$’s.